# Equivalence of right and left cosets of two different subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $A$ and $B$ be two (not necessarily equal) abelian subgroups of $S_5$. If $x$ is an element of $S_5$, under what condition is the following satisfied

$$xA = Bx$$

Update: The original question I encountered was:

If $f, g: \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow S_5$ be two non-trivial homomorphisms, show that there is a $x \in S_5$ such that $$x(image\  f) = (image \  g)x$$

Comment: You need $xA= Bx$ so at the very least $A$ has to have the same size as $B$. If the size of $A$ is the same as $B$ then you are asking if the subgroup $B$ is a conjugate of the subgroup $A$. So given $A$ and $B$ such an $x$ will exist iff the two subgroups are conjugate. I think one needs more info on $A$ or $B$ to answer this question.

Comment: A solution would be: The image of a generator of $Z_5$ has order $5$ in $S_5$, hence is a $5$-cycle. All $5$-cycles in $S_5$ are conjugate. If two elements are conjugate, then so are the subgroups they generated (the converse doesn't hold). For subsets $A, B$ of a group $G$ and an element $x\in G$ the equality $xA = Bx$ is equivalent to $A = x^{-1}Bx$, i.e., to $A$ being conjugated to $B$ via $x$. Now fill in the details...